# How to pass argument to "then" function

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred, q

I'm trying to learn using deferred and I'm stumbled as I'm not getting expected arguments in the "then" block.

```
var makeCall = function (err, param) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1111, err, param);
    deferred.resolve(err, param);
  }, 1000);
  return deferred.promise;
};

makeCall('test', '11').then(function(err, data) {
  console.log(222, err, data);
});
```

Console. with 1111 outputs correct data that was returned from an Ajax call but 222 does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/M2V44/

Comment: What is `callEventSearch` and are you invoking `makeCall`?

Comment: Actually I am getting both `1111` and `222`

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear, I do get 1111 and 222 in correct order, but the content of data is incorrect.  1111 shows valid data but 222 does show null.

Comment: Very sorry. Couldn't reproduce the problem. Can you please create a jsFiddle?

Comment: What is the best way to add q to jsFiddle?

Comment: In the top-left select External Resources and then use the URLs provided [here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/q.js)

Comment: Hmm, It didn't work I got it working on the browser but let me update the question.

Comment: @CodingTwinky you should not use `deferred` objects at all, you should use the promise constructor, exposed from Q with `Q.Promise` instead - it's a lot safer and should be preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deferred.resolve` can accept only one argument and that is to mark the success of the asynchronous call. To notify of the failure, you need to use `deferred.reject`. So your code has to be changed like this

```
var makeCall = function(err,param){
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(1111, err, param);
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(param);
        }
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
};

makeCall(undefined, '11').then(function (data) {
    console.log(222, data);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(333, err);
});
```

This will print `222 '11'`, to simulate the failure case, just invoke `makeCall` with any Truthy value as the first argument, for example

```
makeCall('11')....
```

it will invoke the failure handler, and the output will be `333 '11'`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I'd avoid the deferred altogether.

```
var makeCall = function(err,param){
    if(err) return Q.reject(err);
    return Q(param).delay(1000);
};
```

([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D3F44/))

The usage is similar to thefoureye's answer from earlier, since promises are like synchronous code, you interact with them using return values and catch statements. Nodebacks (`(err,data)`) and callbacks more generally remove many desirable properties from asynchronous code, and promises aim to restore those properties.

```
makeCall(new Error("Hello"),"SomeValue").then(function(cata){
    console.log("Got correct data!",data);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Got error :(",err); // this would happen since we passed an error.
});
```

I also assume that that this function is imaginary, and not representative of a real API.

You mainly use deferred objects when converting an API to promises, which you don't need to in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Note, a) Not certain if interpret Question correctly; b) `Promise` appear not implemented universally same in every browser, nor at jsfiddle. This may be helpful JavaScript Promises http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ (where below piece can be tried at `console`; should also work at mozilla nightly `console`, which appear to implement `Promise` object)

Try this (pattern)

```
var makeCall = function(err, param) {    
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject ) {   
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(1111, err, param);    
  return (err && param) ?
    resolve(err, param)  :  
    reject(Error("error"))      
  })
  }, 1000);
};        
makeCall("test", "11")
.then(function(result) {
console.log(222, result);
makeCall("test2","11");
makeCall("abc", 123) // `chain` test
}, 
function(err) {
console.log(err)
});
```